# Need help using the .not() selector with nested elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to clone an li element but without the  tags. 
I am have tried many different ways but I can make it seem to work.

When I take a look at the html of the li element it still selects the span tags.

Below is the code I am using. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

```
<ul class="todo_list_items" data-category_id="44">
    <li class="tasks" data-task_id="30">
        <!-- Don't want to select this span class -->
        <span class="modify_tasks">
            <a href='#' class='delete_task_name'>Delete</a>
            <a href='#' class='edit_task_name'>Edit Task</a>
        </span>
        <a href="http://localhost/GuruCoders/projcollab/taskdiscussions/index/30/44">Test</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<script>
$(document).on("click", ".edit_task_name", function () {
    var task_id = $(this).data("task_id");
    var previous = $(".tasks[data-task_id=30]").not(".tasks[data-task_id=30] > span").clone();
    console.log(previous.html());
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not() will check against elements in the set, in your case the set consists of only $(".tasks[data-task_id=30]"). not() is testing the span inside it to see if it matches its own parent, so not wont be adjusting your jQuery object for cloning there. An alternative way to achieve what you want might be code similar to this:

```
var   $tasks        = $(".tasks[data-task_id=30]"),
      $modifyTasks  = $tasks.children('span').detach(),
      $cloneOfTasks = $tasks.clone();

$modifyTasks.prependTo($tasks);
$cloneOfTasks.appendTo($tasks.parent());
```

.detach() removes the span without losing events and data so you can put it back in when your done making your clone.

Alternatively this code might be easier to interpret and use:

```
    var $tasks        = $(".tasks[data-task_id=30]");

    $('ul.todo_list_items').append($tasks.contents().not('span').clone().wrap('<li class="tasks" data-task_id="30">').closest('li'));
```

This uses .contents() to grab whats inside the task so you can run not against it. The closest('li') part is needed to ensure the li wrapped around the new element is returned for appending to the ul.

Answer (score 2):

Just clone it and then empty it:

```
var previous = $(".tasks[data-task_id=30]").clone().empty();
```

**EDIT:**  If you only want to remove the span and not other content, then just remove the span from the clone:

```
var previous = $(".tasks[data-task_id=30]").clone();
previous.children("span").remove();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I think you misunderstood my question. I want to select the the whole <li> element but not the <span> in the li element

Comment: just remove the span from the cloned element